# Countdown - Javascript - NOT WORKING in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have an issue with the countdown functionality on my homepage. In chrome the countdown javascript function works fine. But in Firefox and IE, the count is completely different and instead of counting down it counting up. See my code below. Thanks for your help.

Javascript

```
var countdown = $('.countdown-time');
createTimeCicles();
$(window).on('resize', windowSize);

function windowSize() {
  countdown.TimeCircles().destroy();
  createTimeCicles();
  countdown.on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd animationEnd', function() {
    countdown.removeClass('animated bounceIn');
  });
}

function createTimeCicles() {
  countdown.addClass('animated bounceIn');
  countdown.TimeCircles({
    fg_width: 0.011,
    bg_width: 0.1,
    circle_bg_color: '#ffffff',
    time: {
      Days: {
        color: '#66cc9a'
      },
      Hours: {
        color: '#66cc9a'
      },
      Minutes: {
        color: '#66cc9a'
      },
      Seconds: {
        color: '#66cc9a'
      }
    }
  });
  countdown.on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd animationEnd', function() {
    countdown.removeClass('animated bounceIn');
  });
}
```

html

```
<div class="countdown">
  <!-- Timer: Your date here -->
  <div class="countdown-time" data-date="03-31-17 00:00:00"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you [check your console for errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log#t=201610211934187347137) Are you using some kind of plugin? Did you check their issue tracker for any similar problems? What have you done to try and find the source of the problem?

Comment: @MikeC Looks like he's using a jQuery plugin called TimeCircles.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me in Chrome, Firefox and IE. https://jsfiddle.net/f7062snm/1/

Comment: @APAD1 Are you sure? I'm viewing that in IE vs. Chrome and it's counting **down** in Chrome and **up** in IE.

Comment: Sorry for that. I use jQuery plugin as mentioned by MikeC. It doesn't work for firefox as well IE. See movingrabbit.com

Comment: @MikeC you're right, in IE10 it is counting up, but in Chrome 54 and Firefox 49 it is counting down.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I think I figured out your issue. According to the [documentation for TimeCircles](https://github.com/wimbarelds/TimeCircles#setting-your-reference-time), the date you are counting down to or counting up from should be formatted like this: `YYYY-MM-DD` whereas you currently have `MM-DD-YY`. If you reformat the date it seems to work correctly:

```
<div class="countdown-time" data-date="2017-03-31 00:00:00"></div>
```

## [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7062snm/3/)